# Asp.net session: two different users are able to access the same session

Tags: asp.net, session-state

In my website, I am storing some user specific setting in session. But other users are able to access the same session after the first user logout. Isn't session user specific? If yes how come the second user is able to access the session after the first user logs out? In my understanding the second user should not be able to access the first user session even if I don't call session.abandon().

Thanks, Syd

Comment: Can you post some of the code?

Comment: put some code, help us understand better as to what you've done & what the problem is !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session itself and FormsAuthentication are not directly tied together. If you want to make sure your entire session is cleared, you'll need to call `Session.Abandon()` or clear out the individual items when they log out.

Comment: But how come the second user is able to access the first user's session? how did he get the session id of first user?

Comment: You're talking about the same machine/browser, right? The session is tied to a browser cookie, and simply logging out of your application doesn't clear that cookie. So the next user to use the application still has that cookie, and therefore still has the same session. When you abandon the session, the next user will get a new cookie and a new session.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you logout you are actually logging out and not just closing browser i.e. 
call:

```
Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```